# GLUT program link error

Tags: c++, mingw, glut

I want to compile a GLUT program

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    // init GLUT and create Window
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutInitWindowSize(320,320);
    glutCreateWindow("Lighthouse3D- GLUT Tutorial");

    return 1;

}
```

Compile and link command:

```
gcc -o main.exe main.c -lglut32
```

Result:

```
main.o:main.c:(.text.startup+0x1c): undefined reference to `glutInit'
main.o:main.c:(.text.startup+0x28): undefined reference to `glutInitDisplayMode'
main.o:main.c:(.text.startup+0x3c): undefined reference to `glutInitWindowPosition'
main.o:main.c:(.text.startup+0x50): undefined reference to `glutInitWindowSize'
main.o:main.c:(.text.startup+0x5c): undefined reference to `glutCreateWindow'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The actual lib file of glut (3.7.6, called glut32.lib) is in the lib folder of mingw and the include file in include/GL.

What to do now?

Comment: Uh, [this GLUT 3.7.6](http://user.xmission.com/~nate/glut.html)?  If so, use [FreeGLUT](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/), since that's actually maintained.

Comment: Does this help? https://users.cs.jmu.edu/bernstdh/web/common/help/cpp_mingw-glut-setup.php . Looks like you need `g++ ... -mwindows glut32.lib`

Comment: Or better yet, don't use GLUT. Try SDL for example.

Comment: sdl and 3d? why should I do this if there is a 3d-renderer with shaders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try it with `libglut.a` and `libglut32.a` instead of `glut32.lib`. To compile glut programs with minGW.**

Do GLUT for Win32 is a Windows port of the original GLUT library. It’s no longer maintained or supported. The MinGW “w32api” package already comes with two GLUT import libraries, **“libglut.a”** and **“libglut32.a”**, but **doesn’t come with a glut header file.**

If you’ve ever downloaded a GLUT header from the internet, and attempted to link an application against either of these import libraries, you likely would have seen it fail with various undefined references.

[Setting Up GLUT for Win32 With MinGW](http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/computing/using-glut-with-mingw) Look for `Setting Up GLUT for Win32 With MinGW`

**If you want to have your own "build" of libglut32.a and glu32.dll.**

- [Download Source glut-3.7.6-src.zip (4.76 MB)](http://user.xmission.com/~nate/glut.html)
- [Download makefile](http://www.joshuaburkholder.com/glut/makefile)
- Make the following modifications:

Add the following lines to include/GL/glut.h starting at line 12:

```
 #ifdef __MINGW32__
 #define APIENTRY __stdcall
 #define CALLBACK __stdcall
 #endif
```

Comment out line 21 in lib/glut/win32_winproc.c so that it looks:

```
//#include <crtdbg.h>
```

makefile line 5 replace:

**-enable-auto-import** with **--enable-auto-import**

run make

---

Have tried it with the example.c file from the guidance in the link `Setting Up GLUT for Win32 With MinGW`.

With the **prebuild libs** and the **self compiled libs**. Works both.

below is the result.

[image]

**Example GLUT Application**

example.c from the link above `Setting Up GLUT for Win32 With MinGW`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y);
void display(void);


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutCreateWindow("GLUT Test");
  glutKeyboardFunc(&keyboard);
  glutDisplayFunc(&display);
  glutMainLoop();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
  switch (key)
  {
    case '\x1B':
      exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
      break;
  }
}


void display()
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.5f);
    glVertex2f( 0.5f, -0.5f);
    glVertex2f( 0.5f,  0.5f);
    glVertex2f(-0.5f,  0.5f);
  glEnd();

  glFlush();
}
```