# I failed to compile C++ code on Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gcc, compilation, glut

I'm using "glut" library and trying to compile code by gcc compiler, but it gives undesireble result. When I try to build command (`Ctrl+Shift+B`) on Visual Studio Code, The Terminal returns below error messages.

```
Executing task: gcc -I C:\MinGW\include -I C:\Users\Ayata\Documents\Work\freeglut-3.0.0\include -o c:\Users\Ayata\Documents\WorkReport\MakeGameByUsingCpp\main c:\Users\Ayata\Documents\WorkReport\MakeGameByUsingCpp\main.cpp
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Ayata\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0Hoyy5.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `_imp____glutInitWithExit@12'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Ayata\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0Hoyy5.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x3f): undefined reference to `_imp____glutCreateWindowWithExit@8'`
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Ayata\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0Hoyy5.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x162): undefined reference to `glClear@4'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Ayata\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0Hoyy5.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x16a): undefined reference to `_imp__glutSwapBuffers@0'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

I guess incorrect linking to library directory causes this error. But I don't know how to fix it. Would you tell me solution for this error? I'll show my codes below.

P.S. I've succeeded compiling simple "Hello World" program! It worked well!

`main.cpp`

```
#include <GL/glut.h> //importing glut library
int WindowPositionX = 100;
int WindowPositionY = 100;
int WindowWidth = 512;
int WindowHeight = 512;
char WindowTitle[] = "世界の始まり";

void Initialize(void);
void Display(void);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitWindowPosition(WindowPositionX, WindowPositionY);
  glutInitWindowSize(WindowWidth, WindowHeight);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE);
  glutCreateWindow(WindowTitle);
  glutDisplayFunc(Display);
  Initialize();
  glutMainLoop();
  return 0;
}
void Initialize(void){
  glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}
void Display(void) {
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

My code `task.json`. I set `-I` option to search header file in appointed path. (In this case, it will search in `C:\\Users\\Ayata\\Documents\\Work\\freeglut-3.0.0\\include`)

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build main",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "gcc",
            "args": [
                "-I",
                "C:\\MinGW\\include",
                "-I",
                "C:\\Users\\Ayata\\Documents\\Work\\freeglut-3.0.0\\include",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "${file}"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true,
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

Other information:

OS: Windows 10 (64-bit)

gcc version: gcc (MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-3) 8.2.0

header file `glut.h` is located at `C:\Users\Ayata\Documents\Work\freeglut-3.0.0\GL`.

Cpp file `main.cpp` is located at `C:\Users\Ayata\Documents\WorkReport\MakeGameByUsingCpp\main.cpp`.

Json file `task.json` is located at `C:\Users\Ayata\Documents\WorkReport\MakeGameByUsingCpp\.vscode\tasks.json`.

Image of my environment:

[image]

Comment: You don't appear to be linking to the glut library. This has nothing to do with headers or header paths.

Comment: You need to link the FreeGLUT library into your app with something like this parameter: `-lfreeglut` and probably also telling it where to find it: `-LC:\\Users\\Ayata\\Documents\\Work\\freeglut-3.0.0\\lib` (or similar).

Comment: So, what should I do? To tell the truth, This is my first time to use C++ and VSC.

Comment: OK! I'll try it!

Comment: Those are additional args you need to pass to the compiler.

Comment: This  may also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919277/glut-program-link-error

Comment: @drescherjm Thank you! It would be helpful, but I realized I have to do more hard work